# Shiluach haken on injured birds

Tags: halacha, birds, eggs, shiluach-haken, injury

The mitzvah of Shiluach Haken applies only to kosher bird species. My question is, if a bird is of a kosher species but probably Treif from an injury, does it apply in that case? Sources for this would be appreciated. If there is a machloket does it fall on Sephardic vs ashkenazi lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it applies even if the kosher spicie bird is definitely treiffed. See SAY"D 292:1

> The sending of the nest is only practiced with clean birds, even if the mother is torn, and even if there is only one chick or one egg, it is necessary to send it.

> שלוח הקן אינו נוהג אלא בעוף טהור אפילו אם האם טרפה ואפילו אין שם אלא אפרוח אחד או ביצה אחת חייב לשלח: